# If I start input with decimal point in my textbox in C#, I get Input Format Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I'm calculating Fabric Weight in Decimal.

If I enter 0.071, the program works fine.
but if I enter .071 I get input format exception error which is dumb. I want to remove this irritating input format exception error, because a user forgot to enter 0.071.

here are the details.

[image: Screenshot of my Fabric Weight Textbox with decimal point in it]

- Screenshot of my Fabric Weight Textbox with decimal point in it

[image: Exception I'm getting.]

- Exception I'm getting.

  ```
      try
      {
          if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox28.Text, "[^0-9^+]"))
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
              textBox28.Clear();
              textBox28.Focus();
          }

      }

      catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException err){


          MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());

      }


      try
      {

          // Input format error 702
          FabricWeight = float.Parse(textBox28.Text);
      }
      catch (FormatException err)
      {

          MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
  ```

Comment: You're trying to parse a value with only "." in it. Don't do that. Wait until there's at least one digit before you parse it - or use `TryParse` to keep *trying* to parse it, and only show an error if the user hits "ok" or something and it's still invalid..

Comment: Well, there's something you don't see everyday. The reason he added a comment and not an answer is because "Users don't mark Jon Skeet's answers as accepted. The universe accepts them out of a sense of truth and justice." :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to @**Bruniasty**

This works.

"Below this method" I'm storing result in Fabric Weight, you can use this for your program and store to any variable you like after "Try Parsing".

```
    private static void TryToParse(string value)
    {
        double number;
        bool result = double.TryParse(value, out number);

        if (result)
        {

            FabricWeight = number;

        }
        else
        {
            if (value == null) value = "";

        }
    }
```

> Wrote this and worked.

```
TryToParse(textBox28.Text);
```

for more information: Visit this link [MSDN Library: TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Before `FabricWeight = float.Parse(textBox28.Text);` you could add:

```
if(textBox28.Text.StartsWith('.')
{
      textBox28.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}", 0, textBox28.Text);
}
```

And as Jon said - using `TryParse` is way more efficient.

Comment: I just used.

`FabricWeight = float.TryParse(textBox28.Text);`

no overload method for try parse takes 1 arguments.

Comment: TryParse takes 2 arguments - https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: :) float.TryParse returns boolean and should include an out parameter to where you want the result to be stored try float.TryParse(text, out intParsedResult).

Comment: Thanks Bruniasty.
I found a way from your reference to MSDN.Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in event key-press of textbox, its better way:

```
private void textBox28_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "[^0-9^+.]") )
            e.Handled = true;
        if (e.KeyChar == '.' && textBox28.Text.Length == 0)
            e.Handled = true;

        int i = 0;
        foreach (char cc in textBox28.Text)
            if (cc == '.')
                i++;
        if (i >= 1 && e.KeyChar == '.')
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

I test it now. please check this.

Comment: Operator "==" cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'

Comment: same error. Operator "==" cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'